# calling C# dll/COM from C++

Tags: c#, c++, dll, com

I am trying to call a C# dll from visual C++ 6.0 by following the tutorial/instruction at [this site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736)

When I tried it doing a win32 application, it works fine, I can call the C# methods from C++ but when I tried it on my actual project which I think its a MFC project, it doesn't work.

What I mean it doesn't work is that it cannot compile the line:

```
ICalculatorPtr pICalc(__uuidof(ManagedClass));
```

It says the identifier is not define, or something like that but I can point my mouse over it and will show the declaration, I can even right click go to definition and take me to where it is define.

Comment: you can include identifier header file.

Comment: The compiler tells you the error. Either `ICalculatorPtr` or `ManagedClass` is not defined. It's not going to be possible to help you if you won't read error messages. Please don't ever say: *the identifier is not define, or something like that*. Always provide a verbatim error message. And please take some time to understand the error messages. The compiler will tell you which symbol it does not recognise. Use that information to work out why the compiler cannot see it.